# How to create column of data marking information in another column in

Tags: r, data.table

I have a genetic dataset of genome position IDs where 2 IDs can have shared values in one column. I am looking to create another column identifying those with shared information.

For example my data looks like:

```
CP     Shared_CP
1:10   1:10, 1:11, 1:12
1:20   1:56
1:11   1:11, 1:10, 1:12
1:22   1:21, 1:30
1:30   1:30, 1:21
```

I am looking to mark the rows with matching `Shared_CP` information and uniquely identify each grouping, outputting:

```
CP     Shared_CP          matches
1:10   1:10, 1:11, 1:12      1
1:20   1:56                  NA
1:11   1:11, 1:10, 1:12      1
1:22   1:21, 1:30            2
1:30   1:30, 1:21            2
```

I see there are similar questions for creating a new column based on info of other columns, but I haven't found a way to make them work for my problem, at the moment I've been trying to mark rows with shared info based on if they have a comma in the `Shared_CP` column, but I don't know how to then give individual matches a unique identifier to store - any help would be appreciated.

Example input data:

```
structure(list(CP = c("1:10", "1:20", "1:11", "1:22", "1:30"
), Shared_CP = c("1:10, 1:11, 1:12", "1:56", "1:11, 1:10, 1:12", "1:21, 1:30", 
"1:30, 1:21")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Edit: for extra detail, my actual dataset can have several Shared_CP IDs, not just 2. There can also be multiple Shared_CP inputs in a row where the CPs are not the same/included in the Shared_CPs column, I've changed the example to reflect this.

Comment: What exactly does `matches` count?

Comment: Why are the last two 2s?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. It aims to identify any rows which have the same ```Shared_CP``` data and give them a unique ID (so I've just chosen/been trying to do a sequential number per matched Shared_CP information).

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then you want a unique ID (in the form of a number) for a unique `Shared_CP`match. If that's correct then why is there a `1`in the third row?

Comment: In the output, rows 1 and 3 share the same IDs in the ```Shared_CP``` just ordered oppositely, but I am trying to still count this as the same match as both row 1 and 3 ultimately contain 1:10 and 1:11 - sorry for clarity of explanation hope this helps

Comment: What I can offer is this: `df$matches <- ifelse(grepl(".*(\\d:\\d{2}).*\\1", apply(df, 1, paste0, collapse = " ")), 1, 0)`. This records whether there is a match and assigns the value `1`if the condition holds. It however does not group the matches.

Comment: I don't understand how n the fifth row 1:22 is related to 1:21, 1:30. Is that a range of some sort? Are the ID are time stamps and then `1:21 < 1:22 <1:30`? You haven't mentioned that in the quesiton. Also, could Shared_CP have more than two values? And then what? Would it be comparison of `min(Shared_CP) < CP < max(Shared_CP)` per row? There is really a lot of information missing here.

Comment: True, thank you I'll add another edit into the question. I've mentioned in an edit at the bottom that there can be more than 2 values in the Shared_CP column. They are genetic IDs so 1:21 is a distance between itself and 1:20 and 1:30 in the genome

Comment: I've been pretty much intrigued by your post in terms of taking up the challenge. If it is of any interest to you: I've come up with some code to identify the matched value: `df$matched_gene <- str_extract(apply(df, 1, paste0, collapse = " "), "(?=.*(\\d:\\d{2}).*(\\1).*)\\1")`. I don't know at present how to proceed from here to get your desired grouping, but I'm sure it won't be too complicated ... (`str_extract` is from the package `stringr`)

Comment: It'd be helpful if you updated your expected output now that you've updated the example.

Comment: if we add these 2 rows `data.table(CP=c("1:40", "1:50"), Shared_CP=c("1.10", "1.11"))`, what would be the `matches` for these rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants

- to create unique group numbers for `Shared_CP` regardless of the order in which the genome positions appear in `Shared_CP`. So, `1:10, 1:11, 1:12`, `1:11, 1:10, 1:12`, and `1:12, 1:11, 1:10` are all equivalent.
- Furthermore, if there is only one element contained in `Shared_CP` it should be assigned group number `NA`.
- *The value of column `CP` is irrelevant.*

One possible answer using `data.table` is

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
DT[, tmp :=  strsplit(Shared_CP, ", ") %>% unlist() %>% sort() %>% toString(), 
   by = seq(nrow(DT))][
     order(tmp) & tmp %like% ", ", matches := rleid(tmp)][
       , tmp := NULL][]
```

> ```
>      CP        Shared_CP matches
> 1: 1:10 1:10, 1:11, 1:12       1
> 2: 1:20             1:56      NA
> 3: 1:11 1:11, 1:10, 1:12       1
> 4: 1:22       1:21, 1:30       2
> 5: 1:30       1:30, 1:21       2
> ```

This is in line with OP's expected result. In particular, the OP has assigned row 4 to `matches` group 2.

For each row, `Shared_CP` is split into pieces, coerced to a vector of character genome positions which are sorted and combined again to a character *key*. This key is stored in a temporary column `tmp`. The *Shared_CP id number* `matches` is created by applying the `rleid()` function on an ordered version of `tmp`, thereby skipping rows where `tmp` does *not* include `", "`, i.e., where  `Shared_CP` consists only of one element. Finally, `tmp` is removed.

*Piping* (from package `magrittr`) and *chaining* (from `data.table`) is used to improve readability.

Comment: I think this is not right. In the 4th row `CP` is not in `Shared_CP` - therefore `matches` should be `NA`.

Comment: @Georgery, Please, double check OP's expected result. My result is in line with OP's.

Comment: @Georgery, also, please, review carefully the edits the OP has made to the question as well as the many comments. This is why I came to the conclusion that *the value of column `CP` is irrelevant*. I believe the question is only about `Shared_CP`.

Comment: You are correct. This is disappointing, since the original question was asking for something else. My answer fitted the original question but not the update. :( I will disappointedly delete my answer.

Comment: @Georgery, I admit that I was led astray as well by the values in the `CP` column when I started to look at the questions. But the OP has clearly stated *I am looking to mark the rows with matching Shared_CP information and uniquely identify each grouping* when he made the original post. No mentioning of `CP`.